# Python Caching: TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to implement a caching function in Python. The code looks like this:

```
def memoize(func):
    """Store the results of the decorated function for fast lookup
    """

    # Store results in a dict that maps arguments to results
    cache = {}

    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        # If these arguments haven't been seen before, call func() and store the result.
        if (args, kwargs) not in cache:        
            cache[(args, kwargs)] = func(*args, **kwargs)          
        return cache[(args, kwargs)]

    return wrapper

@memoize
def add(a, b):
    print('Sleeping...')
    return a + b

add(1, 2)
```

When I run the code, I get `TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'`.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key of a `dict` must be hashable. You provide an unhashable key `(args,kwargs)` since `kwargs` is a `dict` which is unhashable.

To solve this problem, you should generate a hashable key from the combination of `args` and `kwargs`. For example, you can use (assuming all values of `args` and `kwargs` are hashable)

```
key = ( args , tuple((kwargs.items())))
```

---

```
def memoize(func):
    """Store the results of the decorated function for fast lookup
    """

    # Store results in a dict that maps arguments to results
    cache = {}

    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        # If these arguments haven't been seen before, call func() and store the result.
        key = ( args , tuple((kwargs.items())))
        if key not in cache:        
            cache[key] = cc = func(*args, **kwargs)          
            return cc
        return cache[key]

    return wrapper

@memoize
def add(a, b):
    print('Sleeping...')
    return a + b

print(add(1, 2))
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens, because you are trying to put a dictionary as a key, which is a problem. You can use `frozenset()` to froze the dictionary, so that it would

Answer (score 1):

In this line:

```
cache[(args, kwargs)] = func(*args, **kwargs)
```

you use `kwargs` which is `dict` as part of key. `dict`s are mutable and keys of `dict`s have to be immutable.

Answer (score 1):

Dict is not hashable, which means that you cannot use it in operations that require hash of the objects. Using the object as a key in a dict is one of those things.

In your case in specific, the awards are a dictionary and you are trying to use it as a part of a key for another dictionary.

To make it work, you should create a function that receives the awards and turn it into a number or a string that acts has a fingerprint for any dictionary with the same content.

As a side note, this can also happen if you pass any dict as an argument, nameless, or keyword. If you chose to go with this solution, my advice is to do it in both args and kwargs and recursively check if you have any dict within your args.

As a second side note, on functools module, you have lru_cache for local cache, and you can use cachetools for cache operations and aiocache for an async cache that support the most popular backends other than local cache.